# Extermum under constraint of parabula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Find the closet point on $2x^2-4xy+2y^2-x-y=0$ to the line $9x-7y+16=0$. Hint: the distance between $(x_0,y_0)$ to $ax+by+c=0$ is $d = \frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

For using lagtrange multipliers I need to extract a function $y=f(x)$ alas here I have implicit function. i thought maybe to simplify the implicit function to $2(x-y)^2=(x+y)$ but I can't procceed anymore. another approach can be to express $y_0$ given $x_0$ but when trying to solving the equation i get: $$\begin{align}2y^2-(4x+1)y-x+2x^2=0 \\ \Delta = 16x^2+8x+1-8(2x^2-x) \\\Delta=16x+1\end{align} \\ y_{1,2}=\frac{4x+1\pm\sqrt{16x+1}}{4}$$ which cannot be simplified anymore. Can i simplify the point more? however, even suppose i managed to get the point, how can i use lagrange multipliers here? I have only the disrance function (as defined in the hint $d(x,y)$ but not any constraints of any type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

We have $$2(x-y)^2=x+y\iff (x-y)^2=4\cdot\frac18(x+y)$$

Now comparing with $Y^2=4aX$ whose parametric coordinate is $(at^2,2at)$

$\displaystyle x-y=Y=2at$ and $\displaystyle\frac{x+y}8=aX=a(at^2)$

Find $x,y$ in terms of $t$ and replace their values in $$\frac{|9x-7y+16|}{\sqrt{9^2+(-7)^2}}$$